Anaconda installed but icon does not work
I installed anaconda some months ago and I used it up until now only via commands directly in the terminal (Spyder, Jupyter Lab ...) on a macbook.
Now I need access to the main menu in anaconda. Therefore I called the anaconda file in /Users/name/opt/anaconda3. There I found the anaconda icon (the one in the middle of the picture). If I double click on it, it tells me "The program "anaconda" cannot be opened".
So it seems that anaconda works perfectly fine and is installed. However there is something wrong with the icon .
Does anyone know how I can get into the main menu of anaconda and get a proper icon on my desktop for shortcut accessing it?


Which OS you are working with? MacOS?

perfectly worked - thanks a lot mate! Can I delete the icon in the screenshot which does not work? Or does that cause trouble?

I think it should not be any problem. However do it at own risk. I would be deleting comment and posting an answer because the policy says "don't answer in comments"

If icon is not working open up a terminal and run anaconda-navigator and it should open. But if it fails try re-installation.
If it still doesn't work you would need to raise an issue on anaconda forum
